# Is data which rides on the carrier frequency dangerous?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, frequency, radio

My understanding of broadcasting data via electromagnetic radition is, that the data "rides" on a carrier frequency on which it is radiated.
I am aware of the fact, that those carrier frequencies are below the frequencies of visible light, thus not dangerous like the higher ones (UV, Xray, Gamma).

My question now is, if the data (be it an analog tune from a radio, or a digital WiFi signal) that "rides" on this carrier frequency is oscillating fast enough that it can be considered harmful, because it belongs to the high frequencies greater than visible light.

Comment: I think you should read up on frequency modulation. It will probably answer your question and clear up some misconceptions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of frequency modulation, the information ("data") is contained in slight modulations of the carrier frequency over time. A "1" could mean that the frequency gets a bit higher and a "0" could mean it gets a bit lower.

The modulation in frequency must be tiny enough as to not overlap with the next carrier frequency. And as long as the next higher carrier band doesn't cause health damage, the modulation won't either.

One might argue that the Fourier transform of a frequency-modulated wave also contains modes of higher frequency. But so does the Fourier transform of any finite electromagnetic wave. Maybe an expert can say more about this.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the "data" that is modulated onto the radio frequency of the carrier has a lower frequency than the carrier (this is not an absolute requirement, but few systems exceed it). In case of cell phones, the carrier wave is around 800-1900MHz, while the data rate is on the order of a few Mbit/s, i.e. two orders of magnitude slower than the carrier frequency. Even in case of Wifi the modulation does not exceed a few ten MHz on top of a 2.5 or 5GHz signal. None of this is in the range of optical frequencies or higher, which are in the THz+ range.

Having said all of that, there is substantial danger from high power transmission at all of these and much lower frequencies. It is a very good idea to keep all wireless activity to the lowest possible power level, at which these systems can function.

Comment: -1 For "substantial danger": You can strap your cell phone or wireless router to your head and crank up the transmission all you want - absolutely *nothing* will happen.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: a) I wasn't talking about cell phones, Chris, but about base stations and similar infrastructure, which have far higher transmission power. b) So you have single handedly done clinical trials on the medical consequences of this radiation and you have, beyond any scientific doubt ruled out that it can cause harm? Good for you!